# wso2 IS - User store connection lost

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Good morning.

I have the following problem:

I have created a User Store that points to an Oracle database that has the same schema as wso2 is 6.1. 0, and the users are listed correctly, but from one moment to another, like after 4 hours, the connection is lost and the user option is left thinking to show the users, to solve it, I have to restart the wso2 is and it is solved, or the other option that is faster is to pass the User store created Disable and then Enable, in this way the connection of this user store is refreshed and the incident is solved, but this is not the right thing to do.

```
WSO2 IS 6.1.0
User Store Manager Class: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Error:
TID: [-1234] [] [2024-03-14 08:56:00,711] [830f4183-5d47-4928-87ce-8148de7363dc] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService} - Error while getting user count from user store domain : CGR org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.exception.UserStoreCounterException: Error occurred while retrieving user count
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService.getUserCountWithClaims(UserStoreCountService.java:212)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService.countUsers(UserStoreCountService.java:58)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:449)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:235)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.stub.UserStoreCountServiceStub.countUsers(UserStoreCountServiceStub.java:1980)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserStoreCountClient.countUsers(UserStoreCountClient.java:75)
at org.apache.jsp.user.user_002dmgt_jsp._jspService(user_002dmgt_jsp.java:409)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:537)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:480)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:994)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:485)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor169.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:781)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:444)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:425)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:294)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:83)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:167)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
at org.wso2.carbon.extension.identity.x509Certificate.valve.X509CertificateAuthenticationValve.invoke(X509CertificateAuthenticationValve.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while executing the SQL SELECT COUNT(UM_USER_NAME) AS RESULT FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:258)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserCountWithClaims(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10174)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.count.UserStoreCountService.getUserCountWithClaims(UserStoreCountService.java:204)
... 146 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:239)
... 148 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor230.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:242)
... 150 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while executing the SQL SELECT COUNT(UM_USER_NAME) AS RESULT FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_NAME LIKE ? AND UM_TENANT_ID = ?
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doCountUsersWithClaims(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:3976)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.countUsersWithClaims(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:6558)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getCountUsers(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10583)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserCountWithClaims(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:10213)
... 154 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.setAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2067)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:131)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.getDBConnection(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1306)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doCountUsersWithClaims(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:3946)

Comment: seems you've faced a connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're experiencing an issue with WSO2 Identity Server (IS) 6.1.0 where the connection to a user store backed by an Oracle database gets lost after a certain period of inactivity, requiring a restart or a disable/enable cycle of the user store to refresh the connection.

Check the database connection pool settings in WSO2 IS. Specifically, look for settings related to idle timeouts, max lifetime, and validation queries.

```
    ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT IDLE_TIME 1;
    ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT CONNECT_TIME 1;
    ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_LIMIT = TRUE;
```

To check current idle timeouts,

```
SQL> select * from user_resource_limits where resource_name in ('IDLE_TIME','CONNECT_TIME');
```